# Battery Indicator fixes answer clarification

Tags: nintendo-switch

READ THIS FIRST: **My console is using the latest firmware update**

I bumped into the *not-so-widespread* bug that tells you the incorrect percentage of your battery no matter how long you charged it. Before I say I need answers for this fiasco, let me tell you what I do to my switch before this happened. So my Switch is just 3 months old, whenever I finish my gaming session I power it off. Or when the battery is low and I gotta go to bed I still power it off. It only happened like 2-5 days ago, I dunno. Do you think what I am doing affects the battery indicator, I sure hope it doesn't because I know lithium ion batteries (or modern batteries for short) aren't meant to be charged only if the battery is fully depleted. I decided to consult Nintendo's official support site and I am not satisfied with the results. I don't wanna shell out another 300 dollars just to fix the damn thing. I'm planning to follow these instructions but I dunno if I should trust it even if **it is** from a Nintendo site (link for the instructions I'm talkin' about. **CREDITS GOES TO NINTENDO** https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27111). Now I told you my story I need clarifications for the following instructions.

The reason why I say I need clarifications because the side notes for the ff. sort of contradicts the main respective steps.

**THE BOLD TEXTS BELOW BELONGS TO NINTENDO**

For no. 3 - **Connect the AC adapter directly to the console until the battery is fully charged.
If the battery charge indicator does not reach 100%, simply allow the console to charge for approximately three hours.** Am I suppose to fully charge it for three hours or 'till I reach the inaccurate maximum percentage.

For no. 5 - **Afterward, disconnect the AC adapter and allow the console to display the HOME Menu for approximately three to four hours.
The remaining battery life must be depleted as much as possible.** Am I suppose to leave the console displaying the Home menu after disconnecting the AC Adapter for 3-4 hours (I gonna do it without airplane mode and max brightness)

Comment: When you say you "power it off" when you aren't using it, do you actually mean you put it into sleep mode, or do you really do a full shut down?  (Full shut down requires a confirmation, IIRC, so it might just go to sleep if you don't answer that dialog.)

Answer (score 1):

It will take about 3 hours for a normal functioning Nintendo Switch to charge as it's said [here](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22359).

 So for the third step you should leave your console charging for that time, despite having reached the maximum inaccurate amount. Better a bit more than less when counting to three.

Then, for the fifth step you should turn the Switch on and leave it on the Home Menu to make the battery deplete as much as possible without totally depleting it, so you should be more careful here and keep checking battery once three hours have passed. The time required will vary between three and four hours as said in the step, but it's up to you how much time you have to leave the console turned on.